# Iterating Pointers with begin() and end()

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have a class containing a dynamic array and I want to iterate through it using `begin()` and `end()`. The problem is that I can't seem to get the iteration part to work correctly. So far it looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Deque {
    T** _deque;
    int _front;
    int _back;
public:
    Deque() {
        _deque = new T*[10];
        _front = 5;
        _back = 5;
    }
    // push_back and push_front add elements to the list and move _front/_back
    // ...
    T* begin() {
        return _deque[_front];
    }
    T* end() {
        return _deque[_back];
    }
};
```

But if I add a few items to the list with `push_back` and `push_front` (which work perfectly) then try this

```
for (auto i : deque) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

The first item will always be correct but all following objects will be garbage and will often exceed the size of the array.

How can I automatically iterate over this structure given it's constrained between `_front` and `_back`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't shown where `_deque` gets filled in, but it is probably from a whole bunch of separate allocations?

The issue is that to iterate through an array, you need to point into it.  But you are reading from the array.

A pointer into `_deque` would be `begin() { return _deque + _front; } end() { return _deque + _back; }` and would have type `T**`.

What you have now is morally equivalent to:

```
std::vector<T*> v;
```

...

```
auto it = *(v.begin()); // this is the first pointer stored *in* the container,
                       //  not a pointer to the beginning of the container
auto end = *(v.end());  // this is not even the last pointer stored in the container,
                       // it is reading the element past the end!
for( ; it != end; ++it )
```

which is quite different from the correct iteration:

```
auto it = v.begin();
auto end = v.end();
for( ; it != end; ++it )
```

Most likely your `_deque` variable should have type `T*`, not `T**`, and if you want to store pointers, let `T` be a pointer type.

Comment: Ahh, that all makes sense. You're right, I should have gone with `T*` but didn't quite understand why. Thanks!